# Is Brackets website and text editor safe to use?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, mozilla, text-editor, adobe-brackets

Mozilla recommends Brackets as a text editor for beginners ([Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Installing_basic_software)). After clicking the [link](https://brackets.io/) Chrome states that the website isn't secure. Can others confirm that Brackets software and their website is safe to use?

Comment: Chrome now marks non-https sites as not secure.

Comment: Otherwise this question is not on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on Advanced you may find the answer to your question:

[image]

As you can see, the certificate is rather issued for a different part of the  site  (listed in the above screenshot).

The authors have kept the content of the documentation on GitHub  (http://brackets.io/) because they judge the static pages do not need HTTPS. However, they hosted the `.deb` file  safely (try to download it).

Conclusion: visit http://brackets.io/ both to read the documentation and download the `.deb` file safely

Comment: I get a Windows Firewall warning (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Z8B5WqCCg5NkF6cVVMTFVqejA). Whenever I receive a watrning for applications from known companies I ingnore them, but not sure what's the right thing to do with open source applications. Suggestions?

Comment: *Brackets has a Node.js process integrated into the shell. This is useful for adding functionality that requires deeper native OS access than provided by the Brackets shell* That is why you are getting that warning. Nothing is more trust worthy than an open source application as the source code is public. Instead of being paranoid about open source applications, you should worry about the Windows OS you are using (see my accepted former answer [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98172/what-are-the-privacy-and-security-implications-of-windows-telemetry)) @Ben